# Android Lollipop in MOTO G 2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

The auto-rotate option is getting enabled by itself once I get back to home screen from settings menu even after disabling it.
How to disable the auto-rotate option other than in accessibility?

Comment: Did you try with the quick settings panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) in that case.

1. Create an application based profile and choose your launcher app in it.
2. Create a task followed by the  action **Display → Display AutoRotate  → and Set → Off**.

Now whenever you would come back to home screen or app drawer auto-rotation would turn off automatically.

If the approach noted above doesn't work, then either:

- there is a specific setting overriding auto-rotate which you may need to search. I bet it doesn't exist.
- your "Settings Storage" app's data has gotten corrupted. In that case do factory reset.